# Vue Material Onboarding Component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router, vue-material

I'm pretty new using Onboarding component from Vue Material. I'm looking to use it as a carrousel for photos. I'm trying to implemented on my project but looks a bit messy. Anyone know some documentation a part from the official website?

THANKS

```
    <md-layout md-row md-align="center" md-flex-xsmall="100" md-flex-small="100" md-flex-medium="50">
            <md-boards :md-auto="true" :md-infinite="true" :md-duration="5000" :md-swipeable="true" :md-controls="true" md-swipe-distance="50">
                <md-board id="slide1">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt dolorum quas amet cum vitae, omnis! Illum quas voluptatem, expedita iste, dicta ipsum ea veniam dolore in, quod saepe reiciendis nihil.</p>
                </md-board>
                <md-board id="slide2">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt dolorum quas amet cum vitae, omnis! Illum quas voluptatem, expedita iste, dicta ipsum ea veniam dolore in, quod saepe reiciendis nihil.</p>
                </md-board>
                <md-board id="slide3">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt dolorum quas amet cum vitae, omnis! Illum quas voluptatem, expedita iste, dicta ipsum ea veniam dolore in, quod saepe reiciendis nihil.</p>
                </md-board>
                <md-board id="slide4">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt dolorum quas amet cum vitae, omnis! Illum quas voluptatem, expedita iste, dicta ipsum ea veniam dolore in, quod saepe reiciendis nihil.</p>
                </md-board>
            </md-boards>
</md-layout>
```

all the Lorem P tags are showed on the same slide (num.1), and the other 3 appears empty.

Comment: please provide some code so we can help. this question is not specific enough for stackoverflow.

Comment: @mesqueeb just upload my question

Answer (score 0):

Looks good (but one sytax error - missing : character before 'md-swipe-distance="50"'.

I think it should work if you:
a.) include all required dependencies (CSS, JS)
b.) initialize Vue with material

Code:

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
 <md-layout md-row md-align="center" md-flex-xsmall="100" md-flex-small="100" md-flex-medium="50">
            <md-boards :md-auto="true" :md-infinite="true" :md-duration="5000" :md-swipeable="true" :md-controls="true" :md-swipe-distance="50">
                <md-board id="slide1">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt dolorum quas amet cum vitae, omnis! Illum quas voluptatem, expedita iste, dicta ipsum ea veniam dolore in, quod saepe reiciendis nihil.</p>
                </md-board>
                <md-board id="slide2">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt dolorum quas amet cum vitae, omnis! Illum quas voluptatem, expedita iste, dicta ipsum ea veniam dolore in, quod saepe reiciendis nihil.</p>
                </md-board>
                <md-board id="slide3">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt dolorum quas amet cum vitae, omnis! Illum quas voluptatem, expedita iste, dicta ipsum ea veniam dolore in, quod saepe reiciendis nihil.</p>
                </md-board>
                <md-board id="slide4">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt dolorum quas amet cum vitae, omnis! Illum quas voluptatem, expedita iste, dicta ipsum ea veniam dolore in, quod saepe reiciendis nihil.</p>
                </md-board>
            </md-boards>
</md-layout>
</div>
```

JS:

```
Vue.use(VueMaterial);

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
  , methods: {

  }
});
```

And include "dependencies";

CSS:

```
//unpkg.com/vue-material@0.7.4/dist/vue-material.css
//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic
//fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons
```

JS:

```
//unpkg.com/vue@2.2.4
//unpkg.com/vue-material@latest
```

Codepen to play with it:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vZMqEx

Good luck :D